# Why moderators can see deleted comments while the owner cannot?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, deleted-comments

Recently a moderator said he can see the deleted comments. When I delete a comment, I can no longer see it and I cannot undelete it.

When I delete a comment it means that it's no longer what I believe or I think I was not right. So why should moderators see it, while it no longer exists for me and other users?!

Comment: BTW, there is a small but significant inconvenience in getting a look at deleted comments. The result is that even on a fairly low traffic site like Physics.SE, I have too much to do to go around reading deleted comments without a good reason; and I'm a naturally nois^Winquisitive person.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We need to see comments in case there are issues that arise, like rude or abusive behavior.  Even though we can see them, we have to go through a little bit of a process to see them; it's not like when a question or answer is deleted.  Comments are never shown 'inline' when they're deleted, they're only available through a separate menu.

Comments are necessarily second class citizens (necessarily because their function is normally used for discussion, something that does not scale well at all here), but there ought to be some record of their existence just in case something Bad Happens™.

Comment: There seems to be a bit of a Ongoing Trend™ going on with Unnecessarily™ putting a trademark symbol next to Random Words™

Comment: @davblayn: are you saying that that's A Bad Thing™?

Comment: @davblayn I did it before it was cool. Get off my lawn.

Comment: Github just loves to trademark Anything They Can Get Their Hands On™

Comment: I think you all need to take Chill Pill™.

Answer (score 2):

**Why can moderators see deleted comments?**

Because they are not normal users. They have some extra privileges compared to normal users.
If a user posts any rude or abusive comments, then moderators can take some action.

**Why can't the owner see deleted comments?**

Because they know that comment will not be useful for other users, or is unnecessary.