# Make it clear searching for characters like ™ (the trademark symbol) doesn't work

Tags: feature-request, search

Following [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182155/why-moderators-can-see-deleted-comments-while-the-owner-cannot#comment554585_182156) (that George Stocker used ™ before it was cool) I ran the following search:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E2%84%A2+user%3A16587

Just as I was thinking 'well, he certainly uses ™ a lot' I realised that those were all his posts, not just ones containing ™ (the trademark symbol).

As has been pointed out in comments, even google doesn't support this so I guess it's not an easy fix.

Given that the search results ignore that character/symbol, can it be made clear that this is the case?
I suggest not having it in the search textbox on the results page.

---

Searching for just ™ seems to work as if it wasn't there (results page shows with nothing in the search box), but if I add `user:123` on the end like this:

[image] it shows it in the results page.

Comment: Found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104295/search-and-unicode-characters) which seems to indicate unicode is supported (which I guess is the issue). Not too sure what search terms to use though.

Comment: You might need some way to specify Unicode

Comment: ™ is in the Symbol category, maybe those are filtered before indexing.

Comment: Well, even [big old Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&as_q=George+Stocker&as_epq=%E2%84%A2&as_sitesearch=meta.stackoverflow.com) doesn't support it and just ignores the symbol..

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: If we can't support it then maybe it would be good to remove it from the search box in the results screen (or indicate it some other way).

Comment: It appears that currently if the whole query is "noise" (might be just blank space too) it's just dropped hence you see blank textbox, but when there is even single valid character, only that character counts towards the search but the textbox indeed show the raw query as-is. Good point that it better be changed to show only what's really being searched for, but you need to revise your whole question here and use the "™" only as an example.

Comment: Why are you trying to Punch George Stocker?

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi: I was hoping for him to be proven right. Had he not been I wouldn't have outed him. (honest!)

Comment: Maybe the action of searching for ™ is already trademarked by George Stocker and he hasn't yet licensed it to be used.

Comment: There's an app for that. http://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters

Comment: @EsotericScreenName nice one but not relevant as it only index Stack Overflow. Meta isn't indexed. [proof](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%E2%84%A2&l=&e=&n=&u=meta.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yup, seems that meta isn't indexed. Pity.